# Varibles - Union

Tags: shell-script, shell, ksh

```
FICH10=primero.sh
FICH20=segundo.sh

for i in 10 20
do
   echo $FICH($i)  # I want resolved first $i and then resolver var FICH10
done
```

I want it to first solve `$i` and concatenate it to the `FICH` shoreline and thus return the value of `$FICH10` or `$FICH20` but without having to put the numbers, but they are resolved by the loop

I don't solved with the response asocciate

```
$ for i in 10 20
> do
> echo $((FICH$i))
> done
ksh: line 3: primero: parameter not set
```

Comment: Voters: the "duplicate" solutions work for `bash`, but this question is tagged as `ksh` and they do not work here

Answer (score 3):

Use variable indirection:

```
#!/bin/bash
fich10=primero.sh
fich20=segundo.sh

for i in 10 20 ; do
    var=fich$i
    echo ${!var}
done
```

Note I used small caps for variable names as they aren't system variables.

Comment: Thank you 

$ for i in 10 20
> do
> var=fich$i
> echo ${!var}
> done

but It does not work. That code gets the name of the variable, not its content. 
result of your code var var
I don't need that, I need the content of the variables

Comment: @LinuxVariable: What shell do you use to run it? It works for me in bash.

Answer (score 2):

With bash versions 4.3+, you can use a "nameref":

```bsh
for i in 10 20; do
    declare -n var="FICH$i"
    echo "$var"
done
```

---

We can use `eval` to force a second round of variable substitutions, but as you can see, that's not required. `eval` is generally considered too dangerous to use for most cases.

Comment: Thank's you but It does not work. 
That code gets the name of the variable, not its content.
result of your code
FICH10
FICH20

I don't need that, I need the content of the variables.

Comment: Are you omitting the `-n` flag? Take note of my caveat about the needed bash version.