# Shell Script: Pick one specific global variable with keyward

Tags: shell-script, wildcards

There are multiple global variables with same pattern in my shell script like:

```
VALID_DOMESTIC_ANIMAL=(cat dog)
VALID_ACQUATIC_ANIMAL=(shark dolphin)
```

Now, There is another argument CATAGORY , which could be ACQUATIC/DOMESTIC.
How can I select the expected global variable to iterate ?
I tried following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
VALID_DOMESTIC_ANIMAL=(cat dog)
VALID_ACQUATIC_ANIMAL=(shark dolphin)

CATAGORY=ACQUATIC
VALID_CATAGORY_ANIMAL=VALID_${CATAGORY}_ANIMAL
#echo "VALID_CATAGORY_ANIMAL ${VALID_CATAGORY_ANIMAL}"
for anime in "${VALID_CATAGORY_ANIMAL[@]}"; do
    echo "${anime}"
done
```

I am expecting output `shark dolphin` but I am getting `VALID_ACQUATIC_ANIMAL`

How can I tell bash script that if there exists a variable with same name, use it ?

Comment: In recent versions of bash, you should be able to declare `VALID_CATAGORY_ANIMAL` as a *nameref* - see this related Q&A from yesterday [Varibles - Union](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607525/varibles-union)

Comment: Please first debug the script with https://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: @Quasímodo updated the loop 'done' Copy paste typo
Thanks

Comment: Note that: `foo=(cat, dog)` assigns the values `cat,` and `dog`. The comma isn't needed here to separate the two words, but ends up as part of the first word. (Also, "category" and "aquatic".)

Comment: @likkachu , yeah corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) for showing way forward [Varibles - Union](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607525/varibles-union) .
I used nameref and it worked for me. Performing following change did the trick.

```
-VALID_CATAGORY_ANIMAL=VALID_${CATAGORY}_ANIMAL
+declare -n VALID_CATAGORY_ANIMAL=VALID_${CATAGORY}_ANIMAL
```

Answer (score 0):

This may make it clearer. This variable contains the name of another variable. To get its value the shell must first expand the variable name and then the variable value.

```
for anime in $(eval echo \${$VALID_CATAGORY_ANIMAL[@]}); do
```

`eval` - It take an arguments expands variables and passes to execute by the shell
Since we escaped the first dollar sign, the command will go to execution in this:

```
$(echo ${VALID_ACQUATIC_ANIMAL[@]}
```

You can insert the following line before the loop

```
echo $VALID_CATAGORY_ANIMAL    #VALID_ACQUATIC_ANIMAL
echo \${$VALID_CATAGORY_ANIMAL[@]}    #${VALID_ACQUATIC_ANIMAL[@]}
eval echo \${$VALID_CATAGORY_ANIMAL[@]}    #shark, dolphin
```

Comment: It makes the concept clear. Thanks for it. One followup question: `for anime in $(eval echo \${$VALID_CATAGORY_ANIMAL[@]}); do` here what is the purpose of`echo` ? I understand, eval takes a command as arg. but echo is not really printing anything though.

Comment: @Aftab_Rai, `eval` returns a string as command and its arguments for execution in the shell. If there is no command then we get the following: `eval hi >bash hi: command not found...`